# How to make my Github master branch the only branch to be authorised to access Production resources on GCP?

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, production-environment

I use Github for version control and Google Cloud Platform to orchestrate my resources and store data. I use Kubernetes (google cloud platform) and Jenkins to execute my scripts. BigQuery, Google Cloud Storage (buckets), Cloud MySQL to store my data.

I have a master branch which has production codes and development branch which has development codes. Is there a way how I can restrict only master branch codes to have write access to Production resources on Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: You need to include what tool is fetching the Github code and deploying it to GCP in order to determine if there is a configuration to restrict it to a single branch. You mentioned Jenkins so maybe you're using it? Pls clarify your question.

Comment: Yes, Jenkins is fetching the Github code and on Kubernetes I run a step to clone the Github repository which is happening inside dockerfile.